# Execute a Function before a Timer start

Tags: c#, date, datetime, timer

I am a bit new Here .I have window service in which I have a timer which executes a function after  1 Min interval..I want to Execute function first time before Timer start and then after each Timer Interval...

here is My Code :

```
public partial class ASMSFetchService : ServiceBase
{
    System.Timers.Timer updateAutoSMSTimer;

    public ASMSFetchService()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        updateAutoSMSTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(1 * 60 * 1000);
        updateAutoSMSTimer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(Slots);
        updateAutoSMSTimer.Enabled = true;
        updateAutoSMSTimer.AutoReset = true;
        updateAutoSMSTimer.Start();
     }

    private void Slots(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {method1();}

    private void method1()
    { //SomeOpeartion }
}
```

The function is executing when the 1 timer interval complete ...I want to call the method1() before timer start and then after every Timer interval ....

I have try to put method in the Start() and in the constructor() ..But it is not working ...I am not sure ..But Can it be possible ???

Any suggestion will be Helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to call the method1() before timer start and then after every Timer interval

Then call it before you start the timer

```
method1();
updateAutoSMSTimer.Start();
```

Answer (score 0):

try to call if before start then :

```
 protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            updateAutoSMSTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(1 * 60 * 1000);
            updateAutoSMSTimer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(Slots);
            updateAutoSMSTimer.Enabled = true;
            updateAutoSMSTimer.AutoReset = true;
            method1();
            updateAutoSMSTimer.Start();
         }
```